# How do I ensure the `SIGINT` signal handler is called as many times as `Ctrl+C` is pressed (with `longjmp`)?

Tags: c, linux, signals, sigint, setjmp

## Setup

In the code below, which simply prints some text until it times out, I added a handler (`onintr()`) for `SIGINT`. The handler `onintr()` does the following:

1. Resets itself as the default handler.
2. Prints out some text.
3. Calls `longjmp()`.

## Issue

It seems only the first `Ctrl+C` is interpreted correctly.

After pressing `Ctrl+C` the first time the print statement in `onintr()` appears on the screen and execution returns to where `setjmp()` was called. However, subsequent `Ctrl+C` calls get ignored.

Moreover, resetting `onintr()` as the handler doesn't seem to make a difference. In other words, if I let `SIG_DFL` become the default handler after `onintr()` was called once, subsequent `Ctrl+C`-s get ignored just as when `onintr()` was the handler; and I can't terminate the program.

## The code `signal.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf sjbuf;
void onintr(int);

void 
onintr(int i) 
{
    signal(SIGINT, onintr);
    printf("\nInterrupt(%d)\n", i);
    longjmp(sjbuf, 0);
}

int 
main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int sleep_t = 1; 
    int ctr     = 0; 
    int timeout = 10;

    if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)
        signal(SIGINT, onintr);

    setjmp(sjbuf);
    printf("Starting loop...\n");

    while (ctr < timeout) {
        printf("Going to sleep for %d second(s)\n", sleep_t);
        ctr++;
        sleep(sleep_t);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## Behavior

On Ubuntu 22.04 I get the following:

```
gomfy:signal$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gomfy:signal$ gcc signal.c
gomfy:signal$
gomfy:signal$ ./a.out 
Starting loop...
Going to sleep for 1 second(s)
Going to sleep for 1 second(s)
^C
Interrupt(2)
Starting loop...
Going to sleep for 1 second(s)
Going to sleep for 1 second(s)
^CGoing to sleep for 1 second(s)
^CGoing to sleep for 1 second(s)
^CGoing to sleep for 1 second(s)
^CGoing to sleep for 1 second(s)
^CGoing to sleep for 1 second(s)
Going to sleep for 1 second(s)

gomfy:signal$
```

As you can see the subsequent `Ctrl+C`-s (`^C`) get ignored. Only the first one seems to call the handler.

Comment: It works for me on MacOS, but not on Linux.

Comment: Are you using Clang or GCC on MacOS?

Comment: It defaults to `clang`, so that's what I use.

Comment: You should probably use `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`. `signal()` is older and its behavior varies between implementations.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks! Btw I can also confirm it works on MacOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, from [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) we learn:

> An *async-signal-safe* function is one that can be safely called from within a signal handler.  Many functions are not *async-signal-safe*.  In particular, nonreentrant functions are generally unsafe to call from a signal handler.

This raises two problems:

- `printf` is NOT *async-signal-safe*, and
- mixing signal handlers, [longjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html), and *unsafe* functions leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), as described later in the NOTES section:

> If a signal handler interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and the handler terminates via a call to [longjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) or [siglongjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) and the program subsequently calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

This means if the delivery of **SIGINT** happens to interrupt a call to `printf` then the program can no longer be reliably reasoned about.

---

As a possible red herring, the generic Linux manual for [`sleep(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) makes the claim:

> On Linux, sleep() is implemented via [nanosleep(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).

> Portability notes
> On some systems, sleep() may be implemented using alarm(2) and SIGALRM (POSIX.1 permits this); mixing calls to alarm(2) and sleep() is a bad idea.

and then ambiguously states:

> Using [longjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) from a signal handler or modifying the handling of SIGALRM while sleeping will cause undefined results.

It is not entirely clear if this is only in reference to the previously mentioned `alarm`-based sleeps, but seems likely. The POSIX manual page for [`sleep(3)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) would appear to clarify this by making a similar claim:

> If a signal-catching function interrupts sleep() and calls siglongjmp() or longjmp() to restore an environment saved prior to the sleep() call, the action associated with the SIGALRM signal and the time at which a SIGALRM signal is scheduled to be generated are unspecified.

and [`nanosleep(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) states:

> POSIX.1 explicitly specifies that [nanosleep] does not interact with signals

Suffice to say, it does not appear that `sleep` contributes to this problem, at least on Linux.

---

The Linux manual on [`signal(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) highlights its issues with [portability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html#NOTES), and encourages the use of [`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

An interesting note is:

> If the disposition is set to a function, then first either the disposition is reset to SIG_DFL, or the signal is blocked (see Portability below), and then *handler* is called with argument *signum*. If invocation of the handler caused the signal to be blocked, then the signal is unblocked upon return from the handler.

*The portability section later details the differences between System V (reset) and BSD (block) semantics, and notes that glibc 2+ uses BSD semantics by default (by wrapping around [`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)).*

So if we `longjmp` out of a handler, is the signal ever unblocked?

Linux's overview of signals, [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), ultimately clarifies things in a section labeled ***Execution of signal handlers***, detailing a five step process.

The last part of step one involves:

> Any signals specified in act->sa_mask when registering the handler with [sigprocmask(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) are added to the thread's signal mask.  The signal being delivered is also added to the signal mask, unless SA_NODEFER was specified when registering the handler.  These signals are thus blocked while the handler executes.

While step four and five are:

> 4. When the signal handler returns, control passes to the signal trampoline code.

> 5. The signal trampoline calls sigreturn(2), a system call that uses the information in the stack frame created in step 1 to restore the thread to its state before the signal handler was called.  The thread's signal mask and alternate signal stack settings are restored as part of this procedure.  Upon completion of the call to sigreturn(2), the kernel transfers control back to user space, and the thread recommences execution at the point where it was interrupted by the signal handler.

Again, what happens if we `longjmp` out of a handler? Here is the most important piece of information:

> Note that if the signal handler does not return (e.g., control is transferred out of the handler using [siglongjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html), or the handler executes a new program with execve(2)), then the final step is not performed.  In particular, in such scenarios it is the programmer's responsibility to restore the state of the signal mask (using [sigprocmask(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)), if it is desired to unblock the signals that were blocked on entry to the signal handler. (Note that siglongjmp(3) may or may not restore the signal mask, depending on the savesigs value that was specified in the corresponding call to sigsetjmp(3).)

So the answer is that, by jumping out of the signal handler, the signal mask retains **SIGINT**, and blocks delivery of subsequent signals. The manual mentions the use of [sigprocmask(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) or [sigsetjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) and [siglongjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) to solve this problem.

Here is a simple example of using the latter. `sigsetjmp` needs a non-zero value as its second argument, which tells the pair of functions to save and restore the signal mask. `siglongjmp` simply replaces `longjmp`, and `sigjmp_buf` replaces `jmpbuf`.

`signal` is moved *after* `sigsetjmp` to avoid [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) in the event **SIGINT** is delivered *before* `sigsetjmp` executes, which would cause `siglongjmp` to operate on a garbage `sigjmp_buf`.

Additionally, `ctr` must be declared as `volatile`, as otherwise its value is unspecified. From [`setjmp(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) (applies to `sigsetjmp` as well):

> [...] the values of automatic variables are unspecified after a call to longjmp() if they meet all the following criteria:
>
> - they are local to the function that made the corresponding setjmp() call;
> - their values are changed between the calls to setjmp() and longjmp(); and
> - they are not declared as *volatile*.

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sigjmp_buf sjbuf;

void dump(const char *s)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
}

void onintr(int i)
{
    dump("SIGINT caught. Jumping away...\n");
    siglongjmp(sjbuf, 42);
}

int main(void)
{
    volatile int ctr = 0;
    int timeout = 10;

    if (0 != sigsetjmp(sjbuf, 1))
        dump("Stuck the landing!\n");
    else
        signal(SIGINT, onintr);

    dump("Starting loop...\n");

    while (ctr < timeout) {
        dump("Going to sleep...\n");
        ctr++;
        sleep(1);
    }

    dump("\n");
}
```

```
Starting loop...
Going to sleep...
^CSIGINT caught. Jumping away...
Stuck the landing!
Starting loop...
Going to sleep...
^CSIGINT caught. Jumping away...
Stuck the landing!
Starting loop...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
^CSIGINT caught. Jumping away...
Stuck the landing!
Starting loop...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
^CSIGINT caught. Jumping away...
Stuck the landing!
Starting loop...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
```

*If this still does not work, you may need to define a macro: `_BSD_SOURCE` on glibc 2.19 and earlier or `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` in glibc 2.19 and later. See: [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).*

Comment: Would it be slightly more efficient to install the signal handler only once, when `sigsetjmp` returns zero?  Also I think you need to declare _sjbuf_ as a `sigjmp_buf`

Comment: @pilcrow Yes! Good catch on `sigjmp_buf`, and yes we could install the signal handler in a branch. Thanks!